# Flutter - ListView not scrolling

Tags: flutter, android-layout, user-interface, listview, flutter-layout

In my HomeView I'm using  BottomNavyBar so my scaffold body is a function that returns either of 2 pages.

the feed page is a stateful widget with a Future Builder which returns a ListView Builder like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black12,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 9),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
                future: postNotifier(false).fetchPosts(context: context),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else {
                    var _snapshot = snapshot.data as List;
                    return ListOfPosts(snapshot: _snapshot);
                  }
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

class ListOfPosts extends StatelessWidget {
  final dynamic snapshot;
  const ListOfPosts({Key? key, required this.snapshot}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        PostData postData = snapshot[index];
        return
            FeedPostTile(data: postData);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The Widget I'm using instead of ListTile as the template for post is a work in progress...

```
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
          color: Colors.white70,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 18,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "", // ! post-creator profile name here
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              data.postTime.toString(), //! change to timeago
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 9,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {}, // !! create options
                    icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert_rounded),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                data.postText,
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 13,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  child: SizedBox(
                height: 400,
              )
                  // child: Image.network(), //! make carousel for multiple images
                  )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

VS Code doesn't show any error but the final product, which should be a scrollable list of posts in the feed page isn't scrolling. I'm just following youtube videos and learning. Where am I going wrong? I don't understand.

I looked up for other answers and found out that using multiple/nested scaffolds isn't ideal so I removed scaffold in feed page but that didn't help. Another thing I read is that the ListView might be inside another scrollable widget but I'm unable to figure out where the problem is. And is there a better way to structure the code? Please help.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the above question. I just had to make the listview `primary = false,`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Try wrapping your column in `FeedPostTile` inside a SizedBox and give a height.

**Reason**

Column widget takes maximum available height provided by its parent. In this case it is a ListView.Builder(), which does not have a height constraint. A Container or SizedBox can solve this issue.